# create-export-task | Filter CloudWatch logs using JMESpath

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, jmespath

I want to use [create-export-task](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/create-export-task.html) to store some logs into S3.

Given my CloudWatch logs appear in the following format:

```
{ "message": "Example message", "errorCode": "MY_ERROR_CODE_1", "someFlag": "flag", "otherFlag": "flag2", "level": "error" }
{ "message": "All good", "level": "info" }
```

Is it possible to use the `query` param to filter the response data given the above log structure?

My JMESPath attempts so far have been unsuccessful (e.g. `--query "level"` to only get the level data). I'm not sure whether the log structure is incorrect for this use or if I have misunderstood the purpose of the `query` param.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter multiple identifiers with the output from an AWS CLI.

For example, in your case, to get information about message, and errorCode, you can use the following query:

```
--query '{Message: .message, Error: .errorCode}'
```

In above query:

- `Message` is a label for `message` in the output of the CLI
- `Error` is a label for `errorCode` in the output of the CLI

For more information, you can visit here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that too doesn't seem to have an effect on the export.

Comment: You can use [describe-export-tasks](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/describe-export-tasks.html) to filter information you need based on the output of `describe-export-tasks`

Comment: describe-export-tasks only seems to return metadata about create-export-task requests. It also can't filter the logs export as far as I can tell.

Comment: @evonzz Can you send some example of output?

Comment: {
    "exportTasks": [
        {
            "taskId": "193..",
            "taskName": "myG..",
            "logGroupName": "myG..",
            "from": 1664146800000,
            "to": 1664459190641,
            "destination": "archive...",
            "destinationPrefix": "110939",
            "status": {
                "code": "COMPLETED",
                "message": "Completed succ..."
            },
            "executionInfo": {
                "creationTime": 1665161930124,
                "completionTime": 1665161947665
            }
        }
    ]
}